# Rails route with N number of parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, routes

I have application which allow users to create there on URL for a page on a particular domain.

What I want to achieve is to create URL having variable number of parameters separated by "/". For example:

www.mydomain.com/a

ww.mydomain.com/a/b

www.mydomain.com/a/b/c

and so on. After the root, everything would be considered as parameters. The final result I need in Rails code is two strings:

1."www.mydomain.com" 
2. "a" or "a/b" or "a/b/c" (whatever is after the root)

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want a catch-all route. Add the following line to your `routes.rb` file:

```
map.connect '*path', :controller => 'your_controller' :action => 'your_action'
```

No matter what URL is supplied, the request path is captured and delimited by `/` into an array. You can access this via `params[:path]`.

Since this will match any and every request, any other routes you have should be declared before this one.

Check out Ryan Bates' [catch-all route railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/46-catch-all-route) for more info.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks Jeriko.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the Rails Guide "[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
".

I'm not sure if I get your question, but it seems that you want something close to:

```
map.connect ':first_id/:second_id/:third_id'
```

Comment: Thanks marcgg. Jeriko answer above is what I was looking for.